# Angular ng-repeat + filter runs absurdly slow on iphone 4s

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying for a little while now to implement a levenshtein filter on iPhone4s using repeat + filter on a 1000 items array.

I've tried using bindonce, track by ${}, filter directly through the repeat and I really can't achieve a fair result here.

Anyone got any tip to make this filter run faster? I've been searching for a while now, and though track by would be the solution, but to be honest didnt see any major difference while running it.

Here is a plunker with the result so far, it's using a filter inside the js, but I've tried with a standard orderBy:levenshtein with the same result.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hbAy9ihR4GbAsoQ2EYXt?p=info

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter" ng-change="filter(searchFilter)">

<div class="item" ng-repeat="place in filtered track by place.name">
  {{place.name}}
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1: check how many watches you have on page

2: You can always limit ng-repeat by using filter in controller (reduce it to first 100 items) and add button "add 100" or load more by watching scroll position (I think that you don't need show all elements at one time).

For sure ng-reapeat is very heavy and you should reduce number of displaing items at once.

Comment: I've managed to greatly reduce the payload with a few tweaks to the code, one of them being a debounce to the search itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to have a huge performance boost implementing my own debounce (since it's angular 1.2, debounce is available only 1.3+), and with a few other optimizations you can check on the plnkr.